# Вызов функции из другого класса

Tags: xcode, ios, классы, функции

Есть классы `ViewController` и `SecondViewController`.  
В `ViewController.h` я добавил

```
-(void)addNewItem:(NSString *)newItem;
```

в ViewController.m добавил

```
-(void)addNewItem:(NSString *)newItem
{
    NSLog(@"added");
}
```

в `SecondViewController.m` я импортировал `ViewController.h` и пытаюсь вызвал оттуда метод addNewItem:

```
NSString *item;
[ViewController addNewItem:item]; // на этой строчке у меня ошибка "no known class method for selector 'addNewItem:'"
```

Никак не могу исправить, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: похоже исправил ошибку, в вызове написал так:  
    
    [ViewController alloc] addNewItem:item];

Answer (score 3):

Коротко - нет, не исправили - вам нужно завести переменную типа ViewController *_vc, в каком-то месте проинициализировать ее (создать в этом же класе или передать из вне это уже зависит от того что вам надо) и уже потом сделать [_vc addNewItem:item]. Другой вариант - если вам нужно только как-то повлиять на item -объявить addNewItem методом класса

```
+(void)addNewItem:(NSString *)newItem;
```

Более подробно:

Кажется, вы путаетесь в терминах ООП, у вас есть класс который суть тип данных - описание что именно он содержит (поля, у класса есть только объявления, но нет самих данных, если сделать оговорку о всякой специфике типа указателей на синглтон ) и что этим можно сделать (методы, вот методы-то кажется как раз содержатся в классе), ну и есть методы класса, но это обычно всяческие синглтоны\фабрики либо специфическое преобразование данных типа какой-нибудь обрезки-добавления строки по известному только классу алгоритму, а есть объект у которого-то и есть данные содержащиеся в полях. По-видимому, вы хотите чтобы то что было передано в addNewItem как-то повлияло на объект ViewController, вид которого вы показали рядом или покажете следующим или с которого перешли, но в вашем примере каждый раз создается новый объект (причем без инита, но речь сейчас не о нем) и ему что-то передается, соотвественно, эти данные будут потерены вместе с освобожением объекта, а оно произойдет где-то в теле того же метода (при условии ARC конечно, иначе это просто утечка).

Comment: да, это я понял, я думаю что xcode уже создал объект класса ViewController, мне нужно передать данные этому объекту, но я не знаю как он называется.

Comment: С чего бы ему создавать экземпляр? Возможно это и так если вы используете storyboard, но тут я пас, я с ним никогда не работал - всегда была нужна поддержка 4-ки. В остальных случаях объект сам по себе точно не создается

Comment: да, я пользуюсь Storyboard. На википедии нашел, что
в Objective-C классы сами являются объектами
но почему-то не получается.
Ладно, спасибо за ответ, буду искать другой способ передачи данных, например используя plist.

Comment: Классы это объекты другого типа с описанием собственно класса, так что это тут не причем. По изначальному вопросу - согласно хелпу там все просто - у UIViewController есть свойство storyboard, а у того в свою очередь метод instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier, который вернет объект по идентификатору-строке, думаю, копать нужно в этом направлении. Единственное что - не знаю что будет если передавать данные еще не показаному контролеру

Answer (score 2):

Не пробовали использовать делегаты?

Либо отсылать сообщения слушателям (`Notifications`)?

Насколько я помню напрямую использовать методы из другого класса можно только с помощью делегатов например так: [Example for delegate](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm)

А передавать данные с помощью KVO, например так: [Objective-C биндинги](http://touchdev.ru/documents/2551)